# How to style nested elements based on parent class using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Let's say I want all the links inside white card to be black, and all the links inside orange cards to be white. I can easily do in pure CSS:

```css
.card--primary {
  background-color: white;

  a {
    color: black
  }
}

.card--danger {
  background-color: orange;
  
  a {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

But how can I achieve similar behaviour using Tailwind (or other CSS utility frameworks)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is possible in tailwind 3.1 with the addition of the arbitrary variants feature. The way you would do this is by using a selector on the parent div:

```
<div className="card--primary bg-white [&>a]:text-black" >
  <a/>
  <a/>
<div/>

<div className="card--danger bg-orange [&>a]:text-white" >
  <a/>
  <a/>
<div/>
```

Comment: can you share the reference link here

Comment: @VMM there you go: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants

Comment: useful example:  className=" [&>span>svg_path]:hover:fill-[#F80000] "

Answer (score 22):

**In case of Tailwind CSS**

Read the descriptive and a very brief documentation entry here: [Using arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants).

As I can see you need to change the color of all the `<a>` links no matter how deeply they reside in the `<cards>`. Use an underscore between `&` and `a` selectors - `[&_a]:text-black`. This translates to:

```css
.card--primary {
      
  /* arbitrarily nested <a> links */
  a {
    color: black
  }
}
```

On the other hand the Tailwind directive with `>` between `&` and `a` => `[&>a]:text-black` would result in this css (only the direct child `<a>` nodes would be styled):

```css
.card--primary {
      
  /* direct-child <a> links */
  > a {
    color: black
  }
}
```

**Recap**: the resulting Tailwind HTML for your case:

```html
<div className="card--primary [&_a]:text-black" >
  <a></a> !-- will be black
  <div>
    <a></a> !-- will be black
  </div>
<div/>

<div className="card--danger [&_a]:text-white" >
  <a></a> !-- will be white
  <div>
    <a></a> !-- will be white
  </div>
<div/>
```

That's it. I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 8):

In tailwind v3 you can have [arbitrary group selectors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#arbitrary-groups). This allows you to specify a how a certain element behaves when nested beneath a parent class.

This is useful when you have a templated element needs to appear different under certain scenarios, but doesn't know anything about its parent context.

It requires the addition of the `.group` class, but then you can do something like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <a href="#" class="text-black group-[.card--danger]:text-white">
    Normal Card
  </a>
</div>
<div class="card group card--danger bg-orange-600">
  <a href="#" class="text-black group-[.card--danger]:text-white">Danger Card</a>
</div>
```

Here's an example on Tailwind's playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/IQ4W4BVdjw

Comment: This is clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do this way

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="relative bg-slate-100 flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12 space-y-9">
<div class="relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base">
          <p>White Card with all black links:</p>
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              
              <a href="https://tailwindcss.com"> First Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              
               <a href="https://tailwindcss.com"> Second Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              
               <a href="https://tailwindcss.com"> Third Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="relative bg-orange-700 px-6 pt-10 pb-8 shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base text-white">
          <p>Orange Card with all white links:</p>
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              
              <a href="https://tailwindcss.com"> First Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              
               <a href="https://tailwindcss.com"> Second Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              
               <a href="https://tailwindcss.com"> Third Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see where each of you are coming from, but if you are asking how to do it strictly in Tailwind:

```html
<div class="bg-white text-black">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
<div class="bg-black text-white">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

Everyone else's answer seemed a little bloated.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Tailwind has [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants):

```html
<div className="[&_a]:text-blue-500">
  <a href="#">Foo</a>
</div>
```

Related: starting from v3.4, `*` can be used to style child elements:

```html
<div className="*:text-red-500">
  <a href="#">Foo</a>
  <a href="#">Bar</a>
  <a href="#">Baz</a>
</div>
```