# RadixUI styling Radio groups

Tags: typescript, next.js, styled-components, radix, radix-ui

I am fairly new to Radix UI (with Shadcn/ui) and styling components for that matter. Couldn't figure out a solution for adapting a JSX component to Radix UI:

I am using [Radix UI Radio Groups](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/radio-group) & want to style my component which would look like this upon selection, basically it's this component from [Hyper UI called grid with stacked content and checked](https://www.hyperui.dev/components/application-ui/radio-groups):
[image: Required result]

**Some notes**

- I am using NextJS 13, typescript and well, React :D
- With small adjustment to my code below I can make that radio icon would appear upon select, but not borders wont get active.
- The idea is to have the block border to have these borders (not selected ones will have a thin border.
- Currently in the code I added `{children}` to `RadioGroupPrimitive.Indicator` I know it's wrong as it only handles the button, so the text appears only on select.

I was thinking that I should play with labels somehow, but as the selection is the whole block + icon it seems that I cant put the title and subtitle correctly inside.

I currently am trying to play around and what I came around to is:

```
const RadioGroupItemModern = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof RadioGroupPrimitive.Item>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof RadioGroupPrimitive.Item>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <RadioGroupPrimitive.Item
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        `block w-full bg-white p-3 hover:border-gray-200 focus:outline-none checked:ring-primary `,
        // "aspect-square h-4 w-4 rounded-full border border-primary text-primary ring-offset-background focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    >

    
        <RadioGroupPrimitive.Indicator className="p-4 cursor-pointer rounded-lg border ring-2 ring-primary flex justify-between items-center hover:border-gray-200 focus:ring-2" >
        <div>{children}</div>
          <Icons.checkCircle3 className="h-6 w-6 text-current" />
        </RadioGroupPrimitive.Indicator>
    </RadioGroupPrimitive.Item>


  )
})
RadioGroupItemModern.displayName = RadioGroupPrimitive.Item.displayName
```

And my front-end call would look like this:

```
<RadioGroupItemModern key={choice.value} value={choice.value} id={choice.value} defaultValue={field.value || ''} >
    <div>
    <RadioGroupItemTitle>{choice.text}</RadioGroupItemTitle>
    <RadioGroupItemSubtitle>{choice.description}</RadioGroupItemSubtitle>
    </div>
</RadioGroupItemModern>
```

So now it only shows me the required result when I press the selection (which in this case is invisible).

I tried playing around with the Radix Primitives, adding children in different ways but as I can't figure out the logic on how this would work correctly can't figure out a way as Radix has group radio and labels next to them as different components.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the best answer for this is actually in the `shadcn/ui` examples [here](https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/blob/main/apps/www/app/examples/cards/components/payment-method.tsx).

In this example, there are two important sets of classes you need to apply:

1. The first is to each `RadioGroupItem` inside your `RadioGroup`. They should have the classes `peer sr-only`. The important one here is `peer`, as stated in another answer, that comes form Tailwind.
2. The second is to the element that you want to change the visual appearance of when that `RadioGroupItem` is picked. From the example above, a border is applied to the `Label` inside the `RadioGroupItem` using an attribute selector: `peer-data-[state=checked]:border-primary`. It looks at the `data-state` attribute's value **on the button element the `RadioGroupItem` generates** to determine when to apply the Tailwind class; in this case it's applying a `border-primary`, but that can be anything, including hiding/showing an SVG or whatever.

This should apply for RadixUI and shadcn/ui components, but the method is just using standard attribute selectors.

Also, if you're wondering what `peer` is, [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state) is the relevant documentation from Tailwind!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`peer` from TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state) & `aria-checked:` instead of `checked:` because the Radix component wraps the input in a button. See the smallest possible implementation with RadixUI & shadcn/ui here:

```
<FormItem className="block w-full space-x-3 space-y-0">
  <FormControl>
    <RadioGroupItem value="myValue" className="peer hidden" />
  </FormControl>
  <FormLabel className="block cursor-pointer rounded-md border border-border p-4 font-normal shadow-sm hover:border-primary peer-aria-checked:border-primary peer-aria-checked:ring-1 peer-aria-checked:ring-ring">
    My Label
  </FormLabel>
</FormItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to add my answer here when I found an implementation. Right inside the Examples from the library creator shadcn, basically he's leveraging the presence of `&:has([data-state=checked]` an attribute that Radix UI itself uses to handle the checked item.

He uses the attribute as a boolean to apply the `border-primary` class:

```js
<FormLabel className="[&:has([data-state=checked])>div]:border-primary">
```

For more info have a look at the [GitHub Repo right here](https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/blob/main/apps/www/app/examples/forms/appearance/appearance-form.tsx#L104).

Comment: I had to do [a bit of brushing up on arbitrary variants to understand this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72827101/3486516) but now I understand I'd say this is a more straightforward and flexible solution than others provided.